# Vue JS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good Day, I'm a Beginner at `Vuejs` and I'm trying to fetch some data in the table .. here's my code.

My JS:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $("#token").attr("value");

new Vue({

el: '#incomings',


  methods : {

        getDv: function () {
            this.$http.get('/api/data', function (data) {
                this.$set('dv', data)
            })

        }
  },


  ready : function () {
    this.getDv()
 }


});
```

My View:

```
<div class="container" id="incomings">

    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <tr>

            <th>no</th>

        </tr>

        <tr v-for="a in dv">

            <td>@{{ a.id }}</td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/data', 'DvController@incomingsData');
Route::get('/test', 'DvController@incomings');
```

My Controller:

```
//API's

public function incomingsData(){
    return DV::all();
}



public function incomings(Request $request, DV $disbVchr){
    return view('admin.dv.dv-incomings');
}
```

I've inspected it in the browser and it response an array of `JSON`, but it does not show on the table. ..

Comment: Your `get` callback should use an arrow function so that `this` is properly bound.

Comment: Can you show your output result also.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        this.$http.get('/api/data', function (data) {
            this.$set('dv', data)
        })
```

To

```
        this.$http.get('/api/data', data => this.$set('dv', data))
```

`this` is the first snippet is not bind to the component instance so it will not work.

Information about how `this` works in JS is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).